# Understanding Sorted Linked List

Tags: c

I'm having trouble understanding a sorted linked list in C.

I have the following code:

```
void create(ListNode **pStart, int input)
{

    ListNode *pNew;
    ListNode *pPrevious;
    ListNode *pCurrent;

    pNew = malloc(sizeof(ListNode)); 

    if (pNew != NULL)
    {

        pNew->data = input;
        pNew->pNext = NULL;

        pPrevious = NULL;
        pCurrent = *pStart;

        while (pCurrent != NULL && input > pCurrent->data)
        {
            pPrevious = pCurrent;
            pCurrent = pCurrent->pNext;
        }

        if (pPrevious == NULL)
        {
            pNew->pNext = *pStart;
            *pStart = pNew;
        }
        else
        {
            pPrevious->pNext = pNew;
            pNew->pNext = pCurrent;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%c not inserted. No memory available.\n", input);
    }
    }
```

I have trouble just understanding the part where it says `pCurrent = *pStart;` As isn't pNew technically the first head node? What is the `pCurrent = *pStart` representing?

Comment: You just keep a copy of the header because it is passed by refference

Comment: We need to find the node where the new node should be inserted. After `pCurrent = *pStart;`, `pcurrent` points to the first node of the list. Then we iterate from node to node using `pCurrent` until `input`is greater than `pcurrent->data`. Take a pencil and a piece of paper and draw the list. `pNew` is the pointer to the **new** node,which is not initially part of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to distinguish 3 cases at the time, when `create` is called:

- The list is empty
- The `input` value is smaller or equal to the smallest existing element -> it becomes the new list head
- The `input` value is bigger than the smallest existing element -> it is inserted at a position further into the list

In order to find the position to insert to, the code starts at the list start `*pStart` and continues, until the insertion position is found.

`pNew` is representing the item that you want to insert, it has nothing to do with finding the insertion position.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared it up for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your `pNew` is not the first head node, in fact it is last head node, and if you have only one node after head then it is the first and last head node.

With `pCurrent = *pStart;`, memory address in pointer variable `*pStart` is assigned to `pCurrent`, now since `*pStart` looks like head of your linked list, so `pCurrent` also points to head of linked list after `pCurrent = *pStart;` line of code is executed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`pNew` is added to a certain location so the list remains sorted. `pCurrent` is the node coming after `pNew`, so we start it at the beginning, and search for the right location in the while loop.

Comment: Thanks, i understand it now!